# Can't boot to Ubuntu after reinstalling Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, boot-repair

I had Ubuntu installed with Windows in dual boot configuration. I had some issues with Windows so I decided to reinstall it. I deleted the Windows partition and reinstalled Windows there. I also deleted two other small partitions that I didn't create before and didn't recognize.

I have a SSD with two partitions on it. One is for Windows and the other for Ubuntu.

Now I can't boot to Ubuntu. I tried several ways including boot-repair, but it says to me: `Error: NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr). Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com`

```
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================





Please backup your data before this operation.

Repair blocked: ________________________________________________________________
GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.
Alternatively, you can retry after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option.

Repair blocked: ________________________________________________________________
GPT detected. Please create a BIOS-Boot partition (>1MB, unformatted filesystem, bios_grub flag). This can be performed via tools such as Gparted. Then try again.
Alternatively, you can retry after activating the [Separate /boot/efi partition:] option.

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
sdb5,
using the following options:  set-windows-as-default sdb1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed:  unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups


rm /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
mv /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/sdb1/efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
Mount sdb1 on /mnt/boot-sav/sdb5/boot/efi
```

What should I do now? If I need to reinstall Ubuntu, is there a way to use the Ubuntu partition to recover the apps and configuration from it or I will need to make everything from scratch? I have a lot of apps and configurations on it.

Comment: @Nmath Yes Simple typo.(I edited the question now) I mean Ubuntu `boot-repair`. I used ubuntu usb-live boot to do that.

Comment: @Nmath I diabled the fast startup and window was not hibernated. The windows boot normally instead of the Ubuntu dual boat

Comment: What are these other partitions you deleted. Didn't you investigate what they were for before you nuked them? Did you delete your EFI which is essential to boot EFI operating systems? Are you sure you don't just need to reassert the boot priority in your motherboard BIOS? Can you boot the Ubuntu volume from your motherboard boot options or is it totally unaccessible? The boot repair summary is generally much larger than this. Did you post the whole thing?

Comment: Probably you*just need to reassert the boot priority in your motherboard's UEFI ("BIOS")*... In any case, if you want to use Boot Repair (again, probably not necessary) then make sure you're booting the live session in UEFI mode because that's what the error reported means: You have GPT which for Windows means strictly UEFI mode but you booted the live session for Boot Repair in Legacy mode, hence the suggestion to create *a BIOS-Boot partition*. Don't! First check UEFI settings > Boot, of course.